# Why do we write "char* mystrcpy" in this function? For what reason do we use pointer?

Tags: c

```
char* mystrcpy(char* dest, const char* src) 
{
    int i; 

    for (i = 0; i < mystrlen2(src); i++) dest[i] = src[i]; 
    dest[i] = '\0'; 
    return dest; 
}
```

Comment: I can't answer this question because I don't know why you think you *wouldn't* use pointers in this function.  Can you please tell us what you expected to do instead, and also talk a little about why it surprises you that pointers are involved here?

Comment: Are you asking why the return type is `char*` or why the syntax is `char* mystrcpy`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Strings are implemented in C as arrays of characters and are accessed through a pointer to the first element in the array.  The char*'s in this function are such pointers.

Comment: A correct answer that avoids the myriad misconceptions about pointers, arrays, and strings.

Comment: @TomekM please "accept" Catherine's answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 1):

Functions are often written so that the argument passed into the function is returned as its value, for convenience, to enable more fluent calling code, for example

```
printf("%s", mystrcpy(target, source));
```

Another example of a function returning the destination argument is

```
char *strcat(char *strDestination, const char *strSource);
```